# What is "inlining" means in Next.js "env" document?

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, production-environment

I'm searching of 'env' concept at static build file in Next.js but can't understand what is "inlining" meaning in this context. Could someone give me more specific example?

> This loads process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID into the Node.js environment automatically, allowing you to use it anywhere in your code. **The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser** because of the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix. This **inlining** occurs at build time, so your various NEXT_PUBLIC_ envs need to be set when the project is built.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that when the build tool generates the source code to send to the browser, it will replace the instruction to read an an environment variable with a string representing the value of that environment variable at the time the build happened.